# Android socket client slow

Tags: sockets

I am trying to make a faster socket client to send RGB colors each time, the faster call should be  from 1 to 10 times per second.

I am using this code:

```
try {
        socket = new Socket("192.168.0.9",1234);
        try {
              dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());


            //toServer = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true));
            //out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
            //      new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), false);              
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
        Log.e("Error", "Error");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        Log.e("Error", "Error");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And each time I am changing color from the picker, I am calling this method

```
dataOutputStream.writeUTF(";"+red+";"+green+";"+blue+";"+brightness+";");
```

I have tried a script in python that does the same, 100 times in 2 seconds and I dont have any lags.
What I am getting, is that the python server is waiting for new requests but Android takes time to send them through the socket connection.
I actually tried 3 different method to instance the output write, but only with the DataOutputStream is faster enough but still have some lag.

What is the best approach to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Put a BufferedOutputStream between the DataOutputStream and the socket, and flush the DOS after each writeUTF(). At the peer, use a DataInputStream over a BufferedInputStream.